# 000webhost con mysql error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /storage/ssd2/509/5475509/public_html/webhost.php on line 5?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /storage/ssd2/509/5475509/public_html/webhost.php on line 5

```
 <?php 
 //conectar con el servidor
$conectar=mysql_connect('databases.000webhost.com','id5475509_julian_forus','')

  if (!$conectar){
     echo "No se pudo conectar con el servidor"
 }else{
     $base=mysql_select_db('id5475509_forus');
     if(!$base){
         echo"No se encontro la base de datos";
     }
 }
 //recuperar variables
 $tienda=$_POST['tienda'];
 $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
 $documento=$_POST['documento'];

 //SQL
 $sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('$tienda' ,
                                 '$descripcion' ,          
                                 '$documento')";
//ejecutar sql
$ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);

//verificar ejecucion
if(!$ejecutar){
    echo "Ups... ¡Hubo un error!";
}else{
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>volver</a>";
}   
?>
```

Código php de conexión en la linea 5 me dice que es el error.

Comment: Estáte atento a **poner punto y coma al final de tus líneas**, pues estás mancando al menos dos: aquí: `$conectar=mysql_connect('databases.000webhost.com','id5475509_julian_forus','');` y aquí: `echo "No se pudo conectar con el servidor";`... También, considera blindar tu código contra los ataques de Inyección SQL. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular las variables del `INSERT` y hacer muchísimo daño en tu BD o en tu sistema.

Comment: te hace falta un punto y coma donde esta el echo de no se puede conectar al servidor

Answer (score 2):

Antes del IF de la línea 5 te falta el **;** después del **)** de la línea 3.
Y tal como otro compañero ha comentado abajo, también te falta el punto y coma del final en la línea 6

Te está diciendo que al parsear encuentra un error, que se ha encontrado un IF que no estaba esperando, casi siempre, porque justo antes debería haber un ; como es tu caso, o quizá habría que cerrar algún corchete o paréntesis previos.

```
<?php 
 //conectar con el servidor
$conectar=mysql_connect('databases.000webhost.com','id5475509_julian_forus','');

  if (!$conectar){
     echo "No se pudo conectar con el servidor";
 }else{
     $base=mysql_select_db('id5475509_forus');
     if(!$base){
         echo"No se encontro la base de datos";
     }
 }
 //recuperar variables
 $tienda=$_POST['tienda'];
 $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
 $documento=$_POST['documento'];

 //SQL
 $sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('$tienda' ,
                                 '$descripcion' ,          
                                 '$documento')";
//ejecutar sql
$ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);

//verificar ejecucion
if(!$ejecutar){
    echo "Ups... ¡Hubo un error!";
}else{
    echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>volver</a>";
}   
?>
```

Comment: al `echo` dentro del primer `if` también le falta un `;`

Comment: también, también...